# Detect how many object user touches in one touch? Corona

Tags: function, touch, coronasdk

Can you tell me how to make a function that would detect how many objects one touch intercepts/touches using Corona SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do to solve this is to create a counter for the current number of touches:

```
local counter = 0
```

and a function to handle the touches and updates the counter accordingly:

```
local function touchHandler( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        counter = counter + 1
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        counter = counter - 1
    end
end
```

Then you just add a touch listener to all the objects:

```
object:addEventListener("touch", touchHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that isnt exactly what i meant. What i mean is i want to know how many objects on the screen the user intercept in one touch.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Maybe you should just place them all in the same table and count the table on user interaction.